# Projected ground buffer from 3D line

Tags: line, buffer, 3d, expression

I have a 3D line (e.g. flightpath) and want to create a 2D polygon buffer projected onto the ground (like a shadow), which depends on the altitude - i.e. this would look like a long thin polygon with variable width.

The naïve way would seem to be to create a series of points along the line at suitable spacing, buffer each point based on the exact interpolated altitude of the specific point and then dissolve these circles into one polygon.

However, the above approach is quite expensive if you don't want "gaps" between the circles, and I feel like there must be a more efficient way of doing this directly. Note that this is not quite the same as buffering a line via attribute, as each line segment will have a gradient (i.e. it might start lower or higher than it ends).

Can anyone provide insight to the approach here - is this a known subclass of problem? Note that I'm happy to use any GIS platform or derive something from a suitable algorithm, but not sure where to start here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function tapered_buffer, see from the help:

> This algorithm creates tapered buffers along line geometries, using a
> specified start and end buffer diameter corresponding to the buffer
> diameter at the start and end of the linestrings.

The idea is to first create a line from each point to the next point (points have to be ordered along the travel path or have an attribute that makes clear the sequence of the points). Than for each line segment, create a tapered buffer, with the start buffer diameter coming from the hight attribute of the start point, the end buffer diameter from the end point.

So on your points layer, you can create this buffer with geometry generator (not dissolved, so different buffers all along the line) and pasting the following expression (replace `'hight'` with the name of the attribute that stores the hight). See below how to get a dissolved buffer:

```
tapered_buffer(  
    make_line (
        geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id)),
        geometry (get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1))
    ),
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id), 'hight'
    ),
    attribute (
        get_feature_by_id (@layer, $id+1), 'hight'
    )
)
```

If you want to create an actual geometry and dissolve it to one polygon, use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Geometry by expression`. You can't use here the variable `@layer`, replace the four instances of it by the name of your layer with single quotes, like: `'layer_name'`. You can than dissolve: `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing / Dissolve`.

*Screenshot: input points, labeled with the value of their `hight` attribute:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would produce the desired polygon as follows:

[image]

Note there is a special case when three consecutive points are collinear - the above formula for the bisector will create a divide by zero error. In that case, just find the perpendicular to the line formed by the three points instead.